# column chart where each column has varying heights and widths

Tags: excel-charts

(English is not my native language, so I apologise if some terms are not the best)

I'd like to create a column chart where each column has varying heights and widths.

[image: example table]

The widths are always 1/3 or lower than the heights.

Is there a way to do this in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is called a Marimekko chart. Excel does not have such a chart type out of the box but with careful data preparation and a few charting tricks this can be achieved.

Jon Peltier has a tutorial here https://peltiertech.com/marimekko-charts/ involving a stacked area chart. The instructions are for Excel 2003 and 2007.

Debra Dahlgliesh has a tutorial here https://www.contextures.com/excelmarimekkochart.html for more modern Excel interfaces.